# I want to show multiple pages with routing when user is not Authorized in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I have App.razor file looking like this:

```
@using MyFirstServerSideBlazor.Pages

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
   <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
      <Found Context="routeData">
         <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
               <RouteView DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainHeaderLayout)" RouteData="@routeData" />
            </Authorized>
            <NotAuthorized>               
               <RouteView DefaultLayout="@typeof(LoginBody)" RouteData="@routeData" />
            </NotAuthorized>
         </AuthorizeView>        
      </Found>
      <NotFound>
         <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
         <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
      </NotFound>
   </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

#### Is there some way I can specify what routes I want to show, for Unauthenticated user ?

Lets say I want to let Unauthenticated users to navigate to /Login & /SignUp pages.
I could probable use attributes or something on pages to specify that only authenticated user can view them, but this seems to be inconvenient. I'm wondering is there some better solution ?

I could also make component that shows different pages, but Im unable to change URI routes that way, example would be:

```
<NotAuthorized>               
   <ComponentForUnauthorizedUsers/>
</NotAuthorized>
```

And then in that component have some logic like this:

```
@using MyFirstServerSideBlazor.Componenets.Forms

@inject NavigationManager navigation

@{
   if (ShowLogin)
   {
      <PageTitle>Login</PageTitle>
   }
   else
   {
      <PageTitle>Sign Up</PageTitle>
   } 
}

@{
   if (ShowLogin)
   {
      <LoginForm ChangePageCallback="ChangeToSignUp"/>
   }
   else
   {
      <SignUpComponent ChangePageCallback="ChangeToLogin"/>
   }
}

@code{
   public bool ShowLogin { get; set; } = true;

   public void ChangeToSignUp()
   {
      ShowLogin = false;
      StateHasChanged();
   }    

   public void ChangeToLogin()
   {
      ShowLogin = true;
      StateHasChanged();
   }    
}
```

this also seems wrong, and this way I cannot use Routing.

Comment: [Polite].  Please don't take me wrong here, but "Is there some way I can specify what routes I want to show, for Unauthenticated user ?"  Yes Add or don't add `@attribute [Authorize]` to the page.  Why aren't you using `AuthorizeRouteView` directly in `App` rather that trying to wrap it in a `AuthorizeView`?  Are you overcomplicating this?

Comment: Yeah I know, I could use Authorize attribute for pages. but this to me seems not too convenient, go to every page and add this attribute. I was wondering is there a way to do it differently, to have one place where you could control this and to to go over every page and check for attribute. I mean we use Dependency Inversion and injection, one of it's perks is I can control injected services in one place, if I want to change what service I use just change what "servise" is mapped to "Iservise" and it changes everywhere, I don't have to go through multiple files and change it there.

Comment: And about AuthorizeRouteView, your right I din't know it existed, thanks :)

Comment: It's often the case that the "Standardized" way of how to do something doesn't fully overlap the way you want to do it.  I often find that.   If you think it's worthwhile, write the code to do it your way.  99+% of developer written components probably inherit from `ComponentBase`, mine don't.  I re-wrote it.  That said, I'm not quite sure how you would implement globalized "is it or isn't it authorized".

Answer (score 2):

There's a handful of options here and I wish I knew the best one myself. Here's what I'm currently doing in my app:

**App.Razor**

```
@inject NavigationManager nav

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <AuthorizeView>
        <NotAuthorized>
            @{
                /* THE IMPORTANT PART TO REDIRECT AWAY FROM UNAUTHORIZED PAGES */
                if (new Uri(nav.Uri).AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/login") == false)
                    nav.NavigateTo($"/login/{System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(new Uri(nav.Uri).PathAndQuery)}");
            }
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <Authorizing>
                    <RequestCardTemplate Title="Loading...">
                        <Body>
                            Loading...
                        </Body>
                    </RequestCardTemplate>
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <h1 class="text-center">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</h1>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

**Deciding which pages require auth**

If a page does not require authorization, then I just write the page as normal. If it does require authorization, then I drop the Authorize attribute into the `MyPage.razor` file.

```
@page "/mypage"
@attribute [Authorize]

@* Rest of page stuff *@
```

**Different components**

As you mentioned, you can show different links or something if you want to based on whether a user is logged in (authorized?) or not.

```
@* page stuff... *@

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <a href="/myaccount">My Account</a>
        <a href="/myposts">My Posts</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="/login">Login</a>
        <a href="/signup">Signup</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView

@* more page stuff...
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay with few tweaks I managed to make it Work, In my App.Razor:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
  <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
      <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
          <RouteView DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainHeaderLayout)" RouteData="@routeData" />
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
          <UnauthorizedLayout/>
        </NotAuthorized>
      </AuthorizeView>        
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
      <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
      <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
    </NotFound>
  </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Then in UnauthorizedLayout I have this:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="MainBody">
  <UnauthorizedViewControler/>
</div>
```

In UnauthorizedViewControler component I have this logic:

```
@inject NavigationManager navigation

@{
  if (ShowLogin)
  {
    <LoginPage/>
  }
  else
  {
    <SignUpPage/>
  }
}

@code{
  public bool ShowLogin { get; set; } = true;

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    LocationChanged(null,null);
    navigation.LocationChanged += LocationChanged;
    base.OnInitialized();
  }

  void LocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
  {       
    if (navigation.Uri.Contains("/signup"))
    {
      ShowLogin = false;
    }
    else
    {
      ShowLogin = true;
    }

    StateHasChanged();
  }   
}
```

And for pages themselves :

```
// injects & usings...

@layout UnauthorizedLayout
@page "/Login" 

// HTML & Code...
```

,

```
// injects & usings...

@layout UnauthorizedLayout
@page "/SignUp" 

// HTML & Code...
```

And this works, I have routing for /Login and /SignUp.

Code, could use some cleaning up, but in principle this works.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you manage to find a nicer solution? It seems very bloated. I dont understand why the authorize/allowanonymous doesnt just work out of the box with the AuthorizeRouteView..